# Encrypt password login issue

Tags: php, security, crypt

I am using below code to encrypt user registration password during registration. But the problem is that I can't get login with same password again, I might be because password in DB is different and encrypted and not same as the password user enter.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($username) && !empty($email) && !empty($password)) {
         $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $firstname);
         $lastname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $lastname);
         $username  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $username);
         $email     = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $email);
         $password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $password);

         $sql = "SELECT randsalt FROM user ";

         $select_randsalt_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);

         if(!$select_randsalt_query) {
             die("Query failed".mysqli_error($db_connect));
         }

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_randsalt_query)) {
             $salt = $row['randsalt'];

             ///crypt function takes 2 parameter. one from DB 
             ///and other from user input. 
             // $password = crypt($password, $salt);
         }

         $sql_register ="INSERT INTO user(user_firstname, user_lastname, username, user_email, user_password, user_role )";
         $sql_register .="VALUES('{$firstname}', '{$lastname}', '{$username}', '{$email}', '{$password}', 'Unknown' ) ";

         $query_register = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql_register);

         if(!$query_register) {
             die("Query failed".mysqli_error($db_connect));
         }

         $message = "<h3>Your Registration has been Submitted</h3>";
     } else {
         $message = "<h3>You Can't leave field Empty</h3>";
     }
 } else {
    $message = '';
 }
 ?>
```

I tried to do something like this in login.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];

    //To prevent SQL injection and store into new variable
    $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $Username);
    $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $Password);

    $sql_login = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$Username}' ";

    $query_login = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql_login);

        if(!$query_login){

            die("Query Failed".mysqli_error($db_connect));
        }


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_login)){
            $username       = $row['username'];
            $user_password  = $row['user_password'];
            $user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
            $user_lastname  = $row['user_lastname'];
            $user_email     = $row['user_email'];
            $user_role      = $row['user_role'];
    }

            $Password = crypt($Password, $user_password);

    ///User validation
    if( ($Username === $username && $Password === $user_password) && $user_role === "Admin"){
            //Using session to store information from db
            //Using session from right to left. Right is the variable got from db.

            $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['PASSWORD'] = $user_password ;
            $_SESSION['FIRSTNAME'] = $user_firstname;
            $_SESSION['LASTNAME'] = $user_lastname;
            $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $user_email;
            $_SESSION['ROLE'] = $user_role;

            header("Location: ../admin/index.php");


        }else{  
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
}
?>
```

but this is not working. Sorry people I just entered to the PHP world and don't have deep understanding.

Comment: you need to use a `WHERE` clause in `SELECT`.

Comment: also make sure the password column is long enough to accomodate the hash. If it isn't, you will need to alter your column's length and start over. If it's a length issue, MySQL will fail silently.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to PHP development. Let me make your life a lot easier:

1. Regardless of what your tutorial/book/friend said, [don't escape strings, use prepared statements instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2224584). They're a lot easier to implement safely and your life becomes a heck of a lot easier. (If you rely on escaping, and you remember to escape 2999 out of 3000 parameters a user can control, you're still vulnerable.)
2. Instead of mucking about with `crypt()`, just use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify).

There are updated guides everywhere that can explain how to use these features better, but http://www.phptherightway.com is the one the community points to the most.